# Unexpected Token ... require('React') when running react-native run-ios

Tags: macos, reactjs, react-native

Trying to get code running from my groups repo.... everyone elses seems to install and run fine, but my setup is having issues.  Not sure if this is a dependency issue or not.

Tried removing node / npm / nvm and reinstalling everything including code from repo. Still having issues...

React : *0.14.8*
react-native-cli: *0.2.0*
react-native: *0.24.0*

also react-native-cli was installed globally
with `npm install -g react-native-cli`

command after install : `react-native run-ios`

getting

> /node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native.js:121
>
> ...require('React'),
>
> ^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
>
> at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
>
> at Module._compile (module.js:414:25)
>
> at Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
>
> at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) as .js
>
> at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
>
> at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
>
> at require (module.js:385:17)
>
> at
>   node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:409:22
>
> at Array.map (native)

Comment: Do you get the same error when you run `npm start` in the same directory?

Comment: @BradBumbalough , yes same error when running npm start

Comment: Ok, my guess is node issue. What does `node -v` tell you? I recently had an issue when I upgraded and had to reinstall node because of a similar error.

Comment: @BradBumbalough  v4.2.1 ... I tried removing node ( I believe I got it all too ) and did a reinstall of everything the other day.

Comment: Did you delete your node_modules and attempt a fresh `npm install`? I would check what version of babel-core gets installed. I'm assuming you're using npm > 3.0?

Comment: @BradBumbalough  You are a life saver.  For some reason my npm was at 2.4... updated it to 3.9, removed node_modules and reinstalled.  Its up and running.  Can't believe we didn't think of this. aaaahhhh

Comment: Awesome! glad to help. I'll type of a quick answer for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `npm@3` subDependencies are installed at the same level of your project dependencies (`./node_modules`). My guess is the project is missing some dependencies to run the packager. If you haven't already done so, updgrade to `npm@3` (`$ npm install -g npm`), delete your node_modules folder, then try again.

`$ rm -rf node_modules && npm install`